# is it possible for VBA to detect the error and give a prompt that data not available instead of giving error message?

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a GUI that will setup the pivot table.

For example, I click `button1` it will run and setup the pivot table.

When I click `button3`, it will have a `run time error 1004` because it does not have the value in the data. So is it possible to let VBA accept that error and show a prompt that that data is not available?

[image]

By the way, I'm using this

`ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Test").CurrentPage = "Data1"`

to setup the pivot table.

There are 3 different variables; **Data1**, **Data2**, **Data3**. If **Data3** is not available, it will show the error but I want to have a prompt to show that it is not available.. If you know how to do it, please share it with me! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. For that you need to do appropriate error handling. See this sample code.

```
Sub Sample()
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    '<Your REST OF THE CODE>

LetsContinue:
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    '~~> This gives the exact desription and the error number of the error
    MsgBox "Description     : " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & _
           "Error Number    : " & Err.Number

    '~~> This part resumes the code without breaking it :)
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

Comment: hi sid, I was wondering what if there is continuation of codes after the error is being detected. In other words, I want to continue to run it even after detecting the error. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Yes it is possible but not advisable. What if the following code depends on that particular line? If that line fails then you will get a series of errors.

Comment: ok.. because i have some code that doesnt link to that error and requires to run.. I was thinking of maybe i can do the same thing but using another sub...

Comment: an you show the code in your original post? Maybe I can suggest an alternative.

Comment: Its alittle lengthy.. I'm still trying my best to look into the problem.. Will post it if i'm still stuck and hopefully u can see it! :)

Answer (score 1):

I would just do this:

```
On Error Resume Next ' Don't stop execution when an error occurs.
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Test").CurrentPage = "Data1"

If Err.Number <> 0 Then ' Can also check for a specific error number instead
    'Oops! An error occured.
    MsgBox "Data isn't available."
    Err.Clear
End If

On Error GoTo 0 ' Go back to stoping execution when an error occurs.
```

Comment: @JFC: I wouldn't recommend it as the error could be of any reason. For example what if there is no pivottable "PivotTable1" or PivotField "Test". For these instead of showing appropriate error mesage, it will show "Data isn't available" error which is wrong. I tell you OERN is a devil! LOL

Comment: Sure, but as I explicitly wrote, the OP can check for a specific error number (and/or description) instead of just `Err <> 0`. The OP only asked for a message box that says "data not available". Who am I to say that `Exit Sub` *must* be the next step? Maybe he wants to continue executing along a different branch, I don't know.

Comment: ... which means that no error occurred in the  `ActiveSheet.PivotTables...` statement. What is the question exactly?